# Jenkins - build specific commit on specific branch

Tags: git, maven, svn, github, jenkins

in a jenkinsfile I have a declarative pipeline to build two Maven projects consecutively checked out from the Github repositories

repo2 (https://github.com/MaxHoefl/repo2)

repo1 (https://github.com/MaxHoefl/repo1)

### **Problem:**

How can I checkout a Github repo on a specific branch and even a specific commit on that branch?

### Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
agent any

tools {
    maven "localMaven"
    jdk "localJDK"
    git "localGit"
}

stages {
    stage('Checkout-Repo2') {
        steps {
            git 'https://github.com/MaxHoefl/repo2.git'
            sh "echo {$env.GIT_URL}"
        }
    }
    
    stage('Build-Repo2') {
        steps {
            sh "mvn clean install"
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/target/*.jar', fingerprint: true 
        }
    }
    
    stage('Checkout-Repo1') {
        steps {
            git 'https://github.com/MaxHoefl/repo1.git'
            sh "echo {$env.GIT_URL}"
        }           
    }
    
    stage('Build-Repo1') {
        steps {             
            sh "mvn clean install"
        }   
    }
}

post {
    success {
      echo "Build ID:    {$env.BUILD_ID}"
      echo "Jenkins URL: {$env.JENKINS_URL}"
      echo "Jobname:     {$env.JOB_NAME}"
      echo "Branch:      {$env.BRANCH_NAME}" //null
      echo "Change id:   {$env.CHANGE_ID}"
    }
    
    failure {
      
    }
    
    always {
        echo 'Cleaning up....'
        deleteDir()
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

### Edit 1

Instead of using `git` command

```
stage('Checkout-Repo2') {
        steps {
            git 'https://github.com/MaxHoefl/repo2.git'
        }           
    }
```

I tried using the more general `checkout` command

```
stage('Checkout-Repo2') {
        steps {
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: ''a5e1ddd4e45aeb396b44beece370f891bd0c7fe5'']],
                      userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/MaxHoefl/repo2.git']]])
        }
    }
```

This works. Will try to also include the branch name

Comment: Still dont know how to pass both the branchname and the commit-id to the `name` argument in `checkout`.

Comment: A branch is just a pointer to a commit, so passing branch AND a commit ID is redundant.  Even if we always think in terms of branches with names ,we should think of GIT as succession of commit that sometimes split and merge, branches and tags are just there to help us remember what a particular split or commit is for.

Comment: for me specific-commit-id-case works if I set set `refspec` to the commit id and let `branches` be `["FETCH_HEAD"]` - this way the commit get's fetched and checked out. `checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "FETCH_HEAD"]], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'my.repo', refspec="<commit-id>"]]])`

Answer (score 0):

Go to Snippet Generator tool and select checkout: Check out from version control and provide your commit id in the Branch Specifier (blank for 'any') section. It will build the code based on your commit id.

```
stage("SCM"){
        steps{
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '9f5844216c9f83fba70c5b0817a83eda5338476c']], extensions: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'git@git.example.com:Inhouse/nextjs/demo.git']]])
        }
    }
```